# Dart argument cannot be assigned although it should

Tags: dart, typing, object-oriented-analysis

I am currently having problems understanding this.

Given the following:

```
class Parent {
  Parent(Function(Parent) initializer);
}

class Child extends Parent {
  //type of initializer can't be parsed to something super() expects.
  Child(Function(Child) initializer) : super(initializer); 
}


void foo(Parent parent) => null;
void bar(Child child) => foo(child);
```

This code gives the error:
`The argument type 'dynamic Function(Child)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Parent)'`, however in `foo` and `bar`, there is no error, like expected. What is the difference?

I am very confused by this, since a Child extends a parent, a child, in the object-oriented sense 'is' a parent, and therefore it should work.